# how to show the number of notification in the status bar using android phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am doing a project in android phonegap.Here I want to show the number of notification in the status bar.I have implemented status bar notification using the link [Status Bar Notification](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification).
The code i have changed for showing notification is showing below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="statusbarnotification.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

function show_notify(){
    count = count+1 ;
    //alert(count);
    var title = "message";
    var alerts = "You have "+count+ " message";
    window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify(title, alerts);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick='show_notify()'>Click!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here each call to function show_notify() increment the value of **count** and shows the number of notification in the format "**You have [1 or 2 or 3...] message**".Here  my question is how can i set the value of varibale **count** to zero after clearing notification in the status bar and where should i change the code to redirect to particular page when clicking notification.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a page where all the notifications are. 
You can reset or decrement the count variable when an notification is read. Or when the notifications page is opened.

I'm building an app with JQ-mobi which I really recommend. They offer an data attribute 'data-load'. This is when you can run your methods for resetting the notifications.

http://www.jqmobi.com/index.php